# Obfuscating a module/library

Tags: java, android, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard

I have a library that will be consumed by apps. This module has interfaces and helper classes.

How can I obfuscate the whole module but still allow access to all those interfaces and helper classes?

I tried this:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Then I found myself having to do `--keep` on all my classes in proguard. Is there something I can add to pro guard so that I can keep all those interfaces/helper-classes and still have it as obfuscated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep only the public API of your library from being obfuscated, you need to specify this public API. There are various approaches for libraries:

1. Have separate package for public API and actual implementations, e.g. `com.example.library` contains the public API, whereas `com.example.library.internal` contains the actual implementations that are hidden.
2. Make the actual implementations package private

The ProGuard rules would then look like this:

```
-keep public class com.example.library.* { public protected *; }
```

This will keep only public classes together with their public or protected methods / fields in the com.example.library package.