# Proguard obfuscation of library and app that have a common DTO

Tags: android, build, proguard, obfuscation

I'm going to obfuscate my library that have some Common DTO with app. My app uses this DTO.
I created two proguard-rules file that contains each others settings.

1. When I run app with build variant->"release" and lib-> "debug", app do not recognize my lib DTO that came from web API and nothing loads. It seems normal cause app is minified and lib is not. so they can not communicate with same DTO.
2. But When I chose both build variant-> "release", in compile time the error comes that app do not recognize library DTOs. message is: `Error:(23, 41) error: package com.testlib.model.DTO does not exist` but it really exists.

Do I have to define a common proguard-rules or something like this?

Comment: I deleted your comment below https://stackoverflow.com/a/38042098/229044. Do not leave comments below other people's questions or answers asking them to come view your post. This is your final warning, the next time you do this you will be suspended.

Comment: @meagar Why you delete my comment? with which right? where is written that I can not put link to my question? If  that law is exists in stack overfow so  let me know.

Comment: Yes. Since you wanted a second opinion, I can confirm: commenting on posts asking other people to look at your questions or answers is considered spam. It is not welcome here. The comments will be deleted, and if you don't stop, suspension is a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to use Proguard in Android that way.

If you want to protect some library before exporting that library to other people (example: Google Services are processed with proguard before publishing), you have to keep all public APIs from obfuscation (such as the public DTOs in your case). But since your library module is not for outside use, you probably don't want to process it with Proguard at all.

If you want to protect resulting app, you apply Proguard to the resulting app only. You don't have to apply it to other modules at all. During compilation of application module, Android build tools will bunch up all it's dependencies together and apply Proguard to all of them at once, both app code and library code alike. So your app proguard rules will contain rules for both app code and all it's dependencies.